# SVG path not scaling

Tags: svg

I've looked at a few similar questions but can't seem to find an answer for what seems like something rather easy to do. Like the title says i'm trying to scale an svg using the viewBox method. It's scaling the svg no problem, but it's not scaling the paths within the svg. Here's the code i'm using:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 659 659" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="659" height="659">  

<g> 
    <path fill="none" d="M13.528,293.508C4.551,269.306,0,243.827,0,217.778c0-28.265,5.336-55.765,15.859-81.737l1.802,0.73
        C7.233,162.51,1.945,189.765,1.945,217.778c0,25.817,4.511,51.068,13.407,75.053L13.528,293.508z"></path>

<path d="M217.778,435.556c-41.973,0-82.721-11.965-117.838-34.603c-34.202-22.047-61.498-53.081-78.937-89.745
        c-0.231-0.485-0.025-1.065,0.46-1.296c0.484-0.233,1.065-0.025,1.296,0.46c17.284,36.337,44.337,67.095,78.235,88.946
        c34.803,22.435,75.186,34.293,116.784,34.293c11.55,0,23.139-0.919,34.445-2.733c0.526-0.087,1.029,0.275,1.114,0.806
        c0.085,0.53-0.276,1.029-0.806,1.114C241.123,434.629,229.431,435.556,217.778,435.556z"></path>

<path fill="none" d="M269.654,429.34l-0.461-1.889c30.629-7.484,59.825-21.988,84.433-41.944l1.225,1.511
        C330.021,407.152,300.56,421.787,269.654,429.34z"></path>

<path d="M361.996,380.637c-0.268,0-0.534-0.11-0.726-0.325c-0.357-0.401-0.322-1.015,0.079-1.373
        c45.924-40.941,72.264-99.682,72.264-161.161c0-15.731-1.701-31.424-5.054-46.646c-0.115-0.525,0.216-1.043,0.74-1.159
        c0.526-0.12,1.043,0.216,1.159,0.74c3.384,15.359,5.099,31.194,5.099,47.064c0,62.033-26.576,121.303-72.914,162.612
        C362.457,380.556,362.226,380.637,361.996,380.637z"></path>

<path fill="none" d="M423.026,150.825c-17.539-53.8-56.571-99.477-107.089-125.319l0.886-1.731
        c50.971,26.074,90.355,72.162,108.051,126.447L423.026,150.825z"></path>

<path d="M28.427,113.072c-0.16,0-0.323-0.04-0.474-0.124c-0.469-0.262-0.636-0.855-0.374-1.323C66.089,42.772,138.969,0,217.778,0
        c31.227,0,61.374,6.469,89.603,19.229c0.489,0.221,0.706,0.797,0.485,1.287c-0.221,0.489-0.797,0.706-1.287,0.485
        C278.605,8.356,248.727,1.945,217.778,1.945c-78.106,0-150.336,42.391-188.502,110.63
        C29.098,112.893,28.768,113.072,28.427,113.072z"></path>

</g>

</svg>
```

I've also tried scaling up using CSS but again it only seems to scale the main svg container and not the paths within. Tried using:

```
svg{width:659px;height:659px;}
```

I can get it to scale using

```
transform: scale(1.3);
```

But it's not very accurate in sizing. I need this to be pixel perfect.

Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/alexgomy/j1g4hms8/1/

Comment: Try this: remove the  `height` attribute and change the `width` attribute as you need. Alternatively remove both `width` and `height` attributes from the svg and change the `width` in the CSS. If you need the svg to be as wide as the container remove both `width` and `height` attributes and change the size of the window.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried this. Again all it dopes it scales up the containing svg and the paths within stay the same size.

Comment: If you need the svg to be as wide as the container remove both width and height attributes from the SVG and change the size of the window.

Comment: Hmm still not working correctly. So i removed the width & height attributes from the SVG and added new width & height to the SVG CSS class and it's scaled down but not to the correct size. The SVG has scaled down to 100px. But when i inspect i can see the containing group and paths are scaling to 66px and not 100px. Here's an updated jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/alexgomy/j1g4hms8/28/

Comment: In this case please try changing the viewBox to `viewBox="0 0 436 436"`. Maybe this is what you want

Comment: Perfect. I didn't realise the viewBox needed setting to the actual size of the original SVG. Thanks for pointing me in the right Direction.